# Custom cell editor can't accommodate text in Nimbus Look and Feel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel, tablecelleditor

I want to validate user input in a table cell, and I use the Nimbus Look and Feel. 
Here is the code of a cell editor that validates integer input: [WholeNumberField](http://www.iam.ubc.ca/guides/javatut99/uiswing/components/example-swing/WholeNumberField.java)
It extends `JTextField` and adds input validation.

When I set it for the column it works fine, but it can't accommodate the text:

[image: text cut]

When I use default cell editor, it all looks fine:

[image: normal look]

How can I this editor look like the default editor?

Comment: by defalut JTable returns JLabel as Renderer and JTextField as Editor

Comment: @mKorbel - no, strictly speaking that's not correct: a) "default" is column-class dependent, b) DefaultTableCellRenderer _being_ a JLabel is bad design (though indeed the case accidentally the case for an core JTable :-), c) DefaultCellEditor _is-not_ a JTextField, it can return a JTextField (if instantiated with one) as editing component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WholeNumberField is old code. If you really want to do custom validation then you should be using a [DocumentFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter).

However, in this case, there is no need to create a custom editor. JTable already supports an editor to validate numbers. You just need to override the `isCellEditable(...)` method of the JTable or the TableModel to return `Integer.Class` and the proper renderer and editor will be used.

Edit: Just noticed my suggestion is incorrect.

1. you need to override `getColumnClass(...)` to return Integer.class so the proper renderer/editor can be used.
2. the `isCellEditable(...)` method is used to determine if you can edit a cell.

Comment: I override getColumnClass(int columnIndex) in TableModel and now it works! thanks. (isCellEditable return boolean)

Answer (score 5):

I found that putting the following to my Custom Cell Editor constructor solved the problem for me:

```
Border border = UIManager.getBorder("Table.cellNoFocusBorder");
if (border != null) {
    setBorder(border);
}
```

My Editor extends JTextField.

Answer (score 2):

If you get an *instance* of the `TableCellEditor` from `getDefaultEditor(Object.class)`, it should already be a component that you can validate like in your example.

Comment: no. a) assuming with getDefaultEditor() you mean table.getDefaultEditor(someclass), you don't get a "copy" of the editor, you get the real thing b) the editor rarely _is_ a JTextField, all default implementations return a particular type of JComponent as editing component c) the exact type of the editing component can be anything, the one returned for Object.class indeed is a JTextField, accidentally ;-)